# CGAL project builds successfully with CMake but gives '_BitScanForward64' error when debugging in VSCode with MSVC17

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, vscode-debugger, cgal

Compile CGAL shows “_BitScanForward64”: identifier cannot be found

Background: Long time Visual Studio IDE user, new to VSCode and Visual Studio build tools. I am not an expert on using command line to compile a cmake project but I am trying to learn deeper. The laptop is equipped 64bits AMD6800H CPU and RTX3060 GPU.

I use VSCode for a light C++ project becaused Visual Studio is heavy, and I am going to use CGAL for some functions. Therefore I installed boost(1.82.0) and CGAL(5.5.1) and OpenCV(4.6.0) according to the offical documents. The compiler I chose [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) v143 from Visual Studio 2022(MSVC 17.5.1) and used CMake version 3.26.0-rc6 for building.

The CMake project builds amd64 version well and can generate the .exe when I used the CMake extension in VSCode). However, when I tried to debug the project, the terminal shows:

```
E:\dev\CGAL-5.5.1\include\CGAL/Mpzf.h(193): error C3861: “_BitScanForward64”: identifier cannot be found
E:\dev\CGAL-5.5.1\include\CGAL/Mpzf.h(205): error C3861: “_BitScanReverse64”: identifier cannot be found
```

The json files I wrote:
c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "E:\\dev\\OpenCV\\build\\include\\**",
                "E:\\dev\\boost_1_82_0",
                "E:\\dev\\CGAL-5.5.1\\include\\**",
                "E:\\dev\\CGAL-5.5.1\\auxiliary\\gmp\\include"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "E:\\dev\\CGAL-5.5.1\\auxiliary\\gmp\\lib" /*此处设置为库的lib目录下*/
                ]
            },
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22000.0",
            //"compilerPath": "cl.exe",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
            //"compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/_build/compile_commands.json"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

task.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/I",
                "E:\\dev\\CGAL-5.5.1\\include\\",
                "/I",
                "E:\\dev\\boost_1_82_0",
                "/I",
                "E:\\dev\\OpenCV\\build\\include",
                "/I",
                "E:\\dev\\CGAL-5.5.1\\auxiliary\\gmp\\include",
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/nologo",
                "/Fe${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}",
                "/link",
                "E:\\dev\\CGAL-5.5.1\\auxiliary\\gmp\\lib\\libgmp-10.lib",
                "/link",
                "E:\\dev\\CGAL-5.5.1\\auxiliary\\gmp\\lib\\libmpfr-4.lib"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "cl.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            //"targetArchitecture": "x64",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            //"console": "externalTerminal",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my CMakelist is

```
# Project info ------------------------------------------------------------
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)

project(Color)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Set (remember to change the path for what you need)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "E:/dev") #can be removed if install under directory locally
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "E:/dev/OpenCV/build") #can be removed if install under directory locally
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# include CGAL and OpenCV library -----------------------------------------
find_package(CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS Core )
include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )
include_directories(${CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR})
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

add_executable(Color color.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Color ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES})        
target_link_libraries(Color ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

The error occurs when I tried to debug the project. But using CMake can build .exe successfully.
I searched many solutions for the keywords about "CGAL" and "_BitScanForward64" etc.
One of the solution mentioned he may installed the CGAL library wrongly.
Another said maybe I need to switch to use x64 for building.(But I don't know how to write the task.json and launch.json in this case).

The solutions I tried are:
in task.json set

```
"command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe"
"args": {
    /MACHINE:X64
}
```

Thanks for your reading and hope I could get the solution.

Comment: _BitScanForward64 definitely requires a 64 bit build. Instead of searching, try the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/bitscanforward-bitscanforward64?view=msvc-170). The requirement for a x64 or ARM64 build is stated at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You are trying to compile your program as 32 bits using 64-bit libraries (GMP), that's inconsistent.

Comment: Hey @john Thx for your quick response! I checked thie page before and I know the 64 bit build could be my problem, do you know how to fix it in my case?

Comment: @Xun Sorry but I'm not very familiar with VSCode and CMake. Heavy or not my advice would be to go back to Visual Studio. There are a lot of things you can turn off in VS to make it less heavy.

Comment: Hi @MarcGlisse That's new! I will check it again. BTW, do you know where should I change in those json files?